# how to solve this error : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements?

Tags: r

I have a data (dt) as below (it is just a simplified example, so you can understand my request):

| col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | cell 1 | 1,2 |
| B | cell 2 | 3,5,6 |
| A | cell 3 | 1,2 |
| D | cell 4 | 9,7,8 |

What I want to know is in how many cells I can have the same combinations of col1 and col3 :

So the output should be like this  :

| col 1 | col 3 | col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1,2 | 2 cells |
| B | 3,5,6 | 1 cell |
| D | 9,7,8 | 1 cell |

I was trying this command using "data.table" in r :

```
data.table(table(dt$col1,dt$col3))
```

However it gives me this error :

```
error in table(dt$col1,dt$col3) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

I am doing this in R, data.table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(col1 , col3) %>% summarise("coll2" = paste(length(col3) , "cells"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for as output

Answer (score 4):

You can just aggregate, i.e.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d2)[, .(col2 = .N, col3 = toString(unique(col3))), col1][]

#   col1 col2  col3
#1:    A    2   1_2
#2:    B    1 3_5_6
#3:    D    1 9_7_8
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `count` from `dplyr` and its `name` argument:

```
df %>% 
  count(col1, col3, name = "col2")
```

```
  col1  col3 col2
1    A   1,2    2
2    B 3,5,6    1
3    D 9,7,8    1
```

In case you need `cell` as string, we could add `mutate(col2 = paste(col2, "cell"))`to the code.